# array_map function returning null variable

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, array-map

```
array_map(function ($id) use ($filename) {
                $keyword = Keyword::find($id)->name;
                $filename .= $keyword . '-';
                Log::info($filename);
            }, $input['keyword_id']);
```

I want to add the name of keywords to my filename string variable but the values I see in the log is like :

```
keyword1
keyword2
```

The output I want is one string as a line.

```
keyword1keyword2
```

But as you see, everytime it changes the string instead of appending.

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass the filename as a reference, I think it will work then:

```
use(&$filename)
```

If you don't, it wont change the `$filename` outside of the function.

Edit:
To propose a different approach for what I *think* you're trying to do:

```
foreach ($input['keyword_id'] as $index => $id) {
    $filename .= Keyword::find($id)->name;
    // dont append a "-" if this is the last keyword to be added
    if ($index < sizeof($input['keyword_id'])-1)
        $filename .= '-';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning each item inside the callback.

Just add:

```
return $filename
```

Inside the array_map callback

Comment: You are correct, but I think he actually isn't interested in the array returned by `array_map()`, he just wants to iterate over `$input['keywordid']` and append these keywords names (looked up by `Keyword::find()`) to `$filename` - a simple `foreach` would have done the same trick, with less code, then.

Answer (score 0):

`array_map` simply maps an array to another array with the same number of elements. So you need to return something in the function. The returned array can be *imploded* (concatenated) to get the all the keywords together.

```
$filename = 'myfile.txt';
$keyword_ids = [1,2];
$keywords = array_map(function ($id)  {
                return Keyword::find($id)->name;
            }, $keyword_ids);


$filename = implode('',$keywords) . '-' . $filename;
Log::info($filename);

print( $filename);
//OUTPUTS keyword1keyword2-myfile.txt
```